# onclick attr item inside an iframe, not working in some pages

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am building a html devtools for mobile.

This I do by injecting script and an iframe into the page, and it works fine.

I encounter an odd issue. I have this code which work on all pages except Google and webnovel for some reason.

```
tagStart.el.setAttribute(
             "onclick",
             "window.event.stopImmediatePropagation();this.classList.toggle('readmode');this.querySelector('emchild>.emtext').classList.toggle('readmode')"
);
```

This element exist inside an iframe, any reason why it dose not click when I am on some pages.

The iframe and its container have `max zindex`

Note: I am not using any url, I am injecting a script that create an iframe and add html to it. I am using webview.

Comment: `emchild` is not a valid HTML5 tag. You meant to query for *class* `.emchild` instead?

Comment: nee it is a custom component